# How can i make the specific item in listview change its color when the event displays the same data 3 consecutive times android studio

Tags: android

```
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data");

    rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot clientSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //
                counter++;
            }

            String[] mStrings = new String[counter];
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
            DataModels data = new DataModels();

            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot clientSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                data = clientSnapshot.getValue(DataModels.class);
                String keybot = clientSnapshot.getKey();

                list.add(keybot + "\n"+ data.getEvent() + "\n" + data.getPublished_at());
```

Comment: You should take customadapter and in getView() method you can check multiple condition runtime  as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks i did find a way to make it work somehow without using customadapter.